# Header redirect error with head part of site

Tags: php, html, redirect

Im having a problem with header to redirect. When I try to redirect, it says this...

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at .../head.php:7) in .../init.php on line 3

head.php is as follows:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>grand exchange</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="activate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

init.php is as follows:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);

require 'core/database/connect.php';
require 'core/functions/general.php';
require 'core/functions/users.php';


if(logged_in() === true){  //bans users
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'id','username', 'password','first_name',      'last_name', 'email', 'areacode');
if(user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit(); 
}
}

$errors = array();
ob_flush();
?>
```

I added an ob_start and ob_flush to init.php because ive seen many of the same problems solved with that. Do you guys have an ideas for me?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ob_start` needs to be done before you start any output at all (i.e. before `head.php` is even called, or at the start of `head.php`).

Ideally you would design your application to build all of the HTML *first* and emit it at the end.

Comment: Okay so try to put an ob_start on the page that is calling /head?